# Did the US ever have 51 states in Marvel comics?

Tags: marvel

In X-Statix (2002) #16 (published January 2004), Myles says that "America has fifty-one states":

[image]

Since one of Myles's main character trait is his education (as a well-read Harvard student – well, presumably Harvard dropout at this point), it's unlikely that this is meant to be the character making a mistake.

I can't find any reference to this 51st state; the only relevant thing I can find is the "Fifty State Initiative" (post Civil War, i.e. a few years after this issue), which [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty_State_Initiative) is supposed to "provide a superhero team in every state of the United States."

The next page of the comic shows a map without any apparent extra states:

[image]

(In fact, this map is short a few states: no Alaska or Hawaii, but also apparently the Colorado-Kansas, Pennsylvania-Delaware, and Massachusetts-Rhode Island borders have been dissolved. The colors of the two halves of Michigan are separate, but somehow I doubt that the Upper Peninsula is that 51st state.)

So, **what is the 51st state**?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/51st_state

Comment: @DVK I don't entirely see the relevance of that article. Are you suggesting that Myles is using it as a "joke" about, say, Iraq (given the time period)? That seems most likely I guess, but since the Marvel universe is huge and I don't know that much about most of it, I was wondering whether there was an actual 51st state in it or not.

Comment: I would assume that it was a reference to Puerto Rico, if anything real-life at all. Maybe, DC.

Comment: Are you sure he isn't stood in front of it? Like maybe the tip of Florida seceded from the Union?

Comment: Looks like Texas absorbed Louisiana too

Comment: FWIW, their USAvengers line had 53 covers including Canada (Deadpool), the United Kingdom (Captain Britain, Natch), and Puerto Rico (White Tiger).

Comment: I missed Columbia.